# ruby setter method with arguments for finding a record and setting value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, setter

can I make a setter method with argument like this?

```
def set_value(name)=(new_value)
   u = User.find_by_name(name)
   u.name = new_value
   u.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can do

```
def set_value(name, new_value)
 u = User.find_by_name(name)
 u.name = new_value
 u.save!
end
```